# Is it possible to change how DomainContexts are generated by Silverlight RiaServices?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to change (maybe there is a T4 hidden somewhere...) the way Silverlight Ria Services generates the Domain Contexts classes?

I would like to add an interface to them so my ViewModels can use the interface instead of the class making them more unit testable.

Tks,

André Carlucci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in V1.  But this was a frequent request, so we are working on this for our next release.

http://riaservices.mswish.net

http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services/suggestions/746086-codegeneration-should-be-t4-based-to-enable-custom?ref=title